# Why did my IGBT die? What did I do wrong?

Tags: igbt, component-failure

[image]

I was doing some experiments using the following IGBT:

https://www.pollin.de/productdownloads/D130905D.PDF

I used it to drive a load of ~4.7ish Ohm and ~140ish µH from a capacitor bank of 2350µF.
Each experiment consisted of charging the capacitor bank to a certain voltage and then applying a single pulse of varying length to the gate driver (MCP1407, for schematic I replaced it by the next best thing I could find in the components list), Datasheet:

https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/268/mchp_s_a0001781682_1-2274787.pdf

For maximal switching speed, I did not use a gate resistor, but used a 15.3V Zener soldered directly on the leads to protect the gate from eventual spikes. The inductive load had a diode across (near IGBT) to limit voltage after shut-off. The gate driver was powered by a 12V lead acid battery. I omitted decoupling caps from the schematic (1µF for the gate driver and 11.2nF parallel to the capacitor bank)

As I was increasing the voltage and pulse duration, the IGBT decided to suddenly identify as a 0 Ohm resistor (<3mOhm). All other components survived (except the flimsy wire to the load, which melted in one spot (deliberately chosen weak point)). The gate is now a 16 Ohm resistor.

I gathered the following data on the experiments:

last experiment before the boom:
capacitor bank charged to 450V, a pulse of 500µs (or 5xxµs?, I'm not 100% sure the last 2 digits were 0, unfortunately that was the one number I forgot to write down and only re-added it afterwards from memory). The pulse discharged the capacitors to 432V, dumping ~19J at ~84.6A average current (assuming 500µs and capacitor ratings are accurate).

The next experiment of 720µs pulse duration @450V resulted in a boom. Interestingly, the IGBT has no visible damage and magic smoke only escaped from the wire. Afterwards, the capacitor bank had ~120V remaining.

Now the question: what happened? What did I do wrong?
I thought the datasheet said 160A is fine, or is that the wrong value to look at? However, SSOA also states 480V 100A. Do the other conditions to that value matter/in which direction is a deviation from them safe?
Or was the pulse duration of 720µs too long? How would I go about calculating the max duration from the thermal response data in the datasheet?
Or is there such a thing as switching it too fast?
Or were 12.5V for the gate driver too low? The data from 500µs does not show a dramatic voltage drop on the IGBT, at least not by my calculation: At an average 441V(-4V IGBT drop), expected would be 93A for a 4.7 Ohm resistor or 87.2A with the measured total resistance of wires, contacts and load (5.01 Ohm). Now add ~29µs inductive current ramp-up and a bit of cap ESR and the numbers match.

As I would not like to burn through more IGBTs finding out, I would like to know what I did wrong/what I can do so it does not happen again. Unfortunately, I don't have a DSO that could capture these events.

Comment: Where are your design specs? and limits to failure? and where is your power supply and specs?

Comment: Which ESD precautions did you not follow? Why did you think direct gate drive was valid considering Ciss?

Answer (score 0):

SRF (LC)   ~ 250 Hz
Zo (LC) ~ 250 mohms
R=4.7 , Qs= 0.25/4.7 over-damped

IGBT HGTG20N60B
Rce (@ Tc=25 'C) = 2.6 V/100 A = **26 mohms** +  Vt=1.4 V *(nominal from spec. Figure 4)*
Rce (@ Tc=150'C) = 3.8 V/80 A  =  **48 mohms** + Vt =1.0 V

Imax < 450 V / 4.7 ohms= 96 Amps approx.  96 A * 26 mohms = 2.5 V thus Imax is reduced slightly.

Max Power
SSOA 100A limit   (repetitive)

[image]

**10 ohm  Gate resistor and 15V pulse will improve margins.**

### Conclusion:

SOA margin was minimal and compromised by 0 Ohm Rg.

Simulation

[image]

Comment: So adding a gate resistor also helps? By what mechanism? I thought faster is better as there is less time where the IGBT has both high voltage and high current across it? Sorry, I'm still learning.

Comment: there is also a large gate Q which also has a series R and thus V^2/R=P in added gate power. So the optimal is where resistances are about matched when driving near limits. If not given, always use what they **recommend** in test results. If you derate SOA significantly and have 0R with ESL and Ciss, beware of Q and SRF as it may ring. Thus overdamping degrades Pd on output but matched resistance  reduces ringing from gate Vgs control.  Lower the series R , higher the Q, which cannot be shown in my Simulator unless you add the 0.8 nH/mm and Ciss and Rg etc